# Перестала работать проверка на авторизацию passport (node.js)

Tags: node.js, авторизация, passport

После того, как перенесла роуты /admin/* в отдельный файл, перестала работать проверка на авторизацию (а может и раньше =(  ) 
подскажите, кто знает, пожалуйста, часа четыре уже не могу исправить баг.
в саму сессию юзер сохраняется.
**index.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const templating = require('consolidate');
const app = express();

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));

const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser());

const session = require('cookie-session');
app.use(session({
  name: 'session',
  keys: ['qwe', 'rty'],
  httpOnly: false
}));


const passport = require('passport');
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

const Strategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const Users = require('./models/user');

app.engine('hbs', templating.handlebars);
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('views', `${__dirname}/views`);
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
app.use('/images/flags', express.static(__dirname + '/images/flags'));

require('./routes/admin.js')(app);
require('./routes/game.js')(app);

//Авторизация
passport.use(new Strategy(function(username, password, done) {
  let filtr = {
    table: 'users',
    column1: 'name',
    value1: username,
    column2: 'password',
    value2: password
  };
  Users.auth(filtr, function(err, userdata) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return done(null, false);
    } else if (userdata != undefined) {
      return done(null, {
        user: userdata
      });
    } else {
      return done(null, false);
    }
  });
}));


passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  done(null, id);
});

const auth = passport.authenticate('local', {
  successRedirect: '/admin/relations',
  failureRedirect: '/login'
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('admin', {
    title: 'Админка',
    partials: {
      header: 'partials/header',
      footer: 'partials/footer'
    }
  })
});

app.post('/login', auth);

const mustBeAuthenticated = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
};

app.all('/admin/*', mustBeAuthenticated);

//Главная страница
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.session);
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Главная страница',
    partials: {
      header: 'partials/header',
      footer: 'partials/footer'
    }
  })
});

app.listen(8888);
```

```
**admin.js**
```

```js
const Games = require('./../models/game');
module.exports = function(app) {
  //Список стран (раньше сюда нельзя было зайти без авторизации
  app.get('/admin/countries', function(req, res, next) {
    let filtr = {
      table: 'countries',
      order: 'country'
    };
    Games.showAllOrderByName(filtr, function(error, result) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        res.render('countries', {
          title: 'Страны',
          rows: result,
          partials: {
            header: 'partials/header',
            admin: 'partials/admin',
            footer: 'partials/footer'
          }
        })
      }
    })
  })

  app.get('/admin/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/login');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поместите

```
app.all('/admin/*', mustBeAuthenticated);
```

до

```
require('./routes/admin.js')(app);
require('./routes/game.js')(app);
```

Comment: Ох, спасибо большое, умный человек! Огромное!